# MobaXterm Terminal Settings will not get saved in subsequent runs of a session

Tags: ssh, terminal, mobaxterm

When I spawn a new ssh session in MobaXterm and Change the font family in terminal settings this setting won't persist in new spawns of the session.

How can I fix that?

[image: MobaXterm Terminal Settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Putty.
Create new putty session and set your terminal settings with putty (change font family , forward port , etc) and save your session.
since putty sessions will automatically get imported in MobaXterm you can have persistant terminal configuration in all of you sessions in MobaXterm.

Comment: No that did not work for me. I still have to right-click in the terminal again, select "Change terminal settings" every time. It does not get saved,